# Java Encryption : encrypt integer values

Tags: java, encryption, integer, biginteger

I want to encrypt integer values . I wrote an example for encrypt String values .
**In this integer encryption, I don't want convert integer to String** .

This is my String encryption,

```
String strDataToEncrypt = new String();
String strCipherText = new String();
String strDecryptedText = new String();

try {
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGen.init(128);
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

    final int AES_KEYLENGTH = 128;  
    byte[] iv = new byte[AES_KEYLENGTH / 8];    
    SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom();
    prng.nextBytes(iv);

    Cipher aesCipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

    aesCipherForEncryption.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

    strDataToEncrypt = "Hello World of Encryption using AES ";
    byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = strDataToEncrypt.getBytes();
    byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipherForEncryption.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt);

    strCipherText = new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteCipherText);
    System.out.println("Cipher Text generated using AES is " + strCipherText);


    Cipher aesCipherForDecryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); 

    aesCipherForDecryption.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipherForDecryption.doFinal(byteCipherText);
    strDecryptedText = new String(byteDecryptedText);

    System.out.println(" Decrypted Text message is " + strDecryptedText);

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgo) {
    System.out.println(" No Such Algorithm exists " + noSuchAlgo);
} catch (NoSuchPaddingException noSuchPad) {
    System.out.println(" No Such Padding exists " + noSuchPad);
} catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKey) {
    System.out.println(" Invalid Key " + invalidKey);
} catch (BadPaddingException badPadding) {
    System.out.println(" Bad Padding " + badPadding);
} catch (IllegalBlockSizeException illegalBlockSize) {
    System.out.println(" Illegal Block Size " + illegalBlockSize);
} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException invalidParam) {
    System.out.println(" Invalid Parameter " + invalidParam);
}
```

Encrypted value shouldn't be in **String**. It may be in **BigInteger** or something like it.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean by _"In this integer encryption, I don't want convert integer to String ."_ ? The encrypted result should be an integer?

Comment: All encryption use byte as source data and return byte. If you want to encrypt BigInteger just use toByteArray() and new BigInteger(byte[] val)

Comment: The encrypted result shouldn't be a String .: @SamuelKok

Comment: @JEY : Explain with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code as is and change to encrypt BigInteger:

```
try {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(128);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

        final int AES_KEYLENGTH = 128;  
        byte[] iv = new byte[AES_KEYLENGTH / 8];    
        SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom();
        prng.nextBytes(iv);

        Cipher aesCipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

        aesCipherForEncryption.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        BigInteger bigIntToEncrypt = new BigInteger("123465746443654687461161655434494984631323");
        byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = bigIntToEncrypt.toByteArray();
        byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipherForEncryption.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt);

        BigInteger chipherBigInt = new BigInteger(byteCipherText);
        System.out.println("Cipher Int generated using AES is " + chipherBigInt);


        Cipher aesCipherForDecryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); 

        aesCipherForDecryption.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipherForDecryption.doFinal(byteCipherText);
        BigInteger decryptedInt = new BigInteger(byteDecryptedText);

        System.out.println(" Decrypted Text message is " + decryptedInt);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgo) {
        System.out.println(" No Such Algorithm exists " + noSuchAlgo);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException noSuchPad) {
        System.out.println(" No Such Padding exists " + noSuchPad);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKey) {
        System.out.println(" Invalid Key " + invalidKey);
    } catch (BadPaddingException badPadding) {
        System.out.println(" Bad Padding " + badPadding);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException illegalBlockSize) {
        System.out.println(" Illegal Block Size " + illegalBlockSize);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException invalidParam) {
        System.out.println(" Invalid Parameter " + invalidParam);
    }
```

You can encrypt any type and return a BigInteger from the encrypted data:

```
try {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(128);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

        final int AES_KEYLENGTH = 128;  
        byte[] iv = new byte[AES_KEYLENGTH / 8];    
        SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom();
        prng.nextBytes(iv);

        Cipher aesCipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

        aesCipherForEncryption.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        String dataToEncrypt = "Nice text i want to encrypt";
        byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = dataToEncrypt.getBytes();
        byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipherForEncryption.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt);

        BigInteger chipherBigInt = new BigInteger(byteCipherText);
        System.out.println("Cipher Int generated using AES is " + chipherBigInt);


        Cipher aesCipherForDecryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); 

        aesCipherForDecryption.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipherForDecryption.doFinal(byteCipherText);
        String decryptedInt = new String(byteDecryptedText);

        System.out.println(" Decrypted Text message is " + decryptedInt);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgo) {
        System.out.println(" No Such Algorithm exists " + noSuchAlgo);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException noSuchPad) {
        System.out.println(" No Such Padding exists " + noSuchPad);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKey) {
        System.out.println(" Invalid Key " + invalidKey);
    } catch (BadPaddingException badPadding) {
        System.out.println(" Bad Padding " + badPadding);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException illegalBlockSize) {
        System.out.println(" Illegal Block Size " + illegalBlockSize);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException invalidParam) {
        System.out.println(" Invalid Parameter " + invalidParam);
    }
```

Comment: No it's just how you represents bytes.